# Is an Empty VkCommandBuffer executed when submitted to a queue?

Tags: vulkan

Hey guys I wonder if we submit a VkSubmitInfo containing one empty VkCommandBuffer to the queue, if it will be executed or ignored. I mean will the semaphores in VkSubmitInfo::pWaitSemaphore and VkSubmitInfo::pDestSemaphore still be considered when submitting an empty VkCommandBuffer ?

Looks a stupid question but what I want is to "multiply" the only one semaphore that gets out of the vkAcquireNextImageKHR.

I mean, I want to submit an empty commandbuffer with VkSubmitInfo::pWaitSemaphore pointing to "acquire_semaphore", and having VkSubmitInfo::pDstSemaphore  having as many semaphores as I need.

Comment: Fences aren't inherently more expensive than semaphores. The problem is when using a fence to make some GPU work wait until other GPU work has completed, you put a big bubble in the pipeline compared to using a semaphore: after the GPU work completes, the CPU has to wake up, submit more work, wait for it to get scheduled, etc. all of which is time that the GPU is sitting idle. With a semaphore, the dependent work can start immediately when the prior work is complete. Fences are for GPU->CPU synchronization, semaphores are for GPU->GPU -- choose which to use based on which is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, this is one more reason I don't want to use Fences in vkAcquireImageKHR, since the CPU is already waiting for the vkQueueSubmit to finish and It doesn't need to wait for vkAcquireImageKHR as well.

Comment: vkQueueSubmit doesn't necessarily take very much time. It doesn't have to wait for the image to appear on screen, it only has to make the image available to the "presentation engine" (display driver, system compositor, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if it will be executed or ignored.

What would be the difference? If there are no commands in the command buffer, then executing it will do nothing.

> I mean, I want to submit an empty commandbuffer with VkSubmitInfo::pWaitSemaphore pointing to "acquire_semaphore", and having VkSubmitInfo::pDstSemaphore having as many semaphores as I need.

This has nothing to do with the execution of the CB itself. The behavior of a batch doesn't change just because the CB doesn't do anything.

However, unless you have multiple queues waiting on the completion of this queue's operations, there's really no reason to have multiple destination semaphores. The batch containing the real work could just wait on the `pWaitSemaphores`.

Also, there's no reason to have empty batches that only wait on a single semaphore. Let's say you have batch Q, which signals the `pWaitSemaphores` that this empty batch signals. Well, there's no reason that batch Q's `pDstSemaphores` couldn't signal the semaphores that you want the empty batch to signal. After all, `vkQueueSubmit` semaphore wait operations have, as its destination command scope, *all* subsequent commands for that queue from `vkQueueSubmit` calls, the current one or subsequent ones.

So you would only need an empty batch if you have to wait on multiple semaphores that are signals from different batches on different queues. And such a complex dependency layout strongly suggests an over-complicated dependency design that will lead to reduced performance.

Even waiting on acquire makes no sense for this. You only need to wait on acquire if that queue is going to manipulate to the acquired image. Well, you can't manipulate an image from multiple queues simultaneously. So there's no point in signaling a bunch of semaphores when acquire completes; that's why acquire only takes one.

> So I want to simulate a Fence only with semaphores and see what goes faster.

This suggests strongly that you're thinking about things incorrectly.

You use a fence when you want the CPU to detect the completion of a GPU operation. For `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`, you would use a fence if you need the CPU to know when the image has been acquired.

Semaphores are about the GPU detecting when a GPU operation has completed, regardless of whether the operation comes from a queue or not. So if the GPU needs to wait until an image is acquired, you use a semaphore.

It doesn't matter which is faster because they do different things.

Comment: Yes, there will be many queues, and I am not submitting one VkSubmitInfo with many command buffers inside it, I am submitting an array of VkSubmitInfo. The point is, if VkSubmitInfo has an Empty CommandBuffer will the pWaitSemaphore and pDstSemaphore still be waited/flagged or not.

Comment: @alcoforado: Why would they *not be*? And equally importantly, why can't you just put those `pDstSemaphore`s on the batch that signals the `pWaitSemaphore` that this empty batch is waiting on?

Comment: Well there is nothing in the Kronos Spec saying what would happen if the command buffer is empty. A driver manufacturer may choose just to ignore the hole submission. Also who is signaling the first semaphore is the VkAcquireImageKHR function, not a batch. And this function returns one semaphore and one fence only.

Comment: @alcoforado: "*Well there is nothing in the Kronos Spec saying what would happen if the command buffer is empty.*" No, you've got it backwards. The specification states that batches will signal semaphores. ***Period***. Unless the spec has an exemption from signaling semaphores for empty batches, they still must signal semaphores from a batch.

Comment: Also I understand that a Fence can be used to GPU-CPU but it can also be used to 1 signal and multiple waits in the GPU only side.  Semaphores are always restricted to 1 signal - 1 wait.

Comment: @alcoforado: "*it can also be used to 1 signal and multiple waits in the GPU only side*" No, it can't. There are no Vulkan functions for the *GPU* to wait on fences. `vkWaitForFences` causes the CPU thread to block until those fences are signaled; it changes nothing about GPU progress. You may be thinking of events, not fences.

Comment: Oh thanks, one more thing where did you get the "Well, you can't manipulate an image from multiple threads simultaneously." Two command buffers can bind to different pipelines with both having the same final image. I can't find anywhere where they say it may not run in parallel.

Comment: Ok, consider a case of one graphic queue. I have many shaders, and multiple pipelines, one for each shader to write in the same image. Every shader generates an array of VkSubmitInfo that is then concatenated and submitted in one huge QueueSubmit. Isn't that a case to use my strategy ?

Comment: I am asking each shader to return an array of VkSubmitInfo so the shaders can always have the option to use semaphores to syncronize their inner cycles of "load subresources" and drawing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166272/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-alcoforado).

Comment: Yeah the hole mess was thinking that a semaphore is a signal-wait between two command buffers. It is not, it is block in the entire queue. Vulkan Api kind of induces this thinking because semaphores are submitted together with the batches in vkQueueSubmit. So we think that the command buffer that was submitted with a semaphore in the VkSubmitInfo::pWaitSemaphores will wait for the Batch submitted with the same semaphore in VkSubmitInfo::pDstSemaphore.

Comment: I think the semaphore Behaveour would be more clear if we could submit them separate from the command buffers. We would have two functions:

VkWaitSemaphore(vkQueue *queue, vkSemaphore *s,int count)

VkSignalSemaphore(vkQueue *queue, vkSemaphore *s, int count)

Comment: @alcoforado: The reason `vkQueueSubmit` takes multiple batches is because `vkQueueSubmit` (and everything that goes along with it) is *expensive*. So you only want to pay that cost when absolutely necessary.